# How to affect just one key in a nested object (React)?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, immutability

So, I have a component setup as such:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    validatedFields: {
      email: {
        uiState: null,
        message: null,
      },
      password: {
        uiState: null,
        message: null,
      },
    },
  }

  ...etc
}
```

In a function inside this `Login` component, I loop through field values and validate them. Inside the loop, if that particular value is invalid, I want to change its `uiState` to the string `'error'`

Eg if just email was wrong, the new state would be:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    validatedFields: {
      email: {
        uiState: 'error',
        message: null,
      },
      password: {
        uiState: null,
        message: null,
      },
    },
  }

  ...etc
}
```

What is the easiest way to do this with ES6?

I would like to stay away from things like:

```
let oldState = this.state
oldState.validatedFields.email.message = 'error'
this.setState(oldState)
```

This seems very verbose for what is effectively changing the value of one key inside a nested array.

What are alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
this.setState({
    validatedFields: Object.assign({}, this.state.validatedFields,
        email: {
            uiState: 'error',
            message: null,
        })
});
```

It surely isn't less verbose for a single update but you may wrap this in a function and pass it the field you want to update (like pass in the new email object). This prevents mutation as well as allows you to use email object directly obtained from somewhere else.

Comment: Yup, wrapping it in a function seems like a sensible thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: One other question, if I wrap this as a function in a separate module, how do I pass `this` into it so I can call `this.setState`, etc?

Comment: You can do `export class ComponentName` to get access to `ComponentName`'s functions but I would not recommend doing that in this case. It is better to handle the state update within the component itself.